# Protect a PDF while viewing

Tags: android, pdf, encryption

I have an encrypted PDF in the external memory (sdcard), and I want to make it secure on the Android  device while reading. The problem is:

- I need a plain copy to open it
- Third party apps may offer an option to share the app (e.g. Adobe
  Reader).

1) First approach was like it do it with images. The File is decrypted via a **CipherInputstream**. This cipher inputStream reads the file into an android **MemoryFile** (which is basically withour a path, but visible for Android only). This decrypted MemoryFile can generate a Bitmap via Bitmapfactory. Unforteunatly I can not open the PDF from a memory file (I found no way to do so...)

2) Second approach was to make a **plain copy (also on SD) and immedeately to delete it after opening**. This works fine for videos playing in videos. I decrypt the file to another place on sdcard - I start to play with the videoView on the plain file - I delete the file as soon as it is playing. The video view then works fine, even tough the file is deleted during playing. The problem for the PDF viewer (seen on Adobe, Polaris) is that the file must not be deleted while theses viewers sho it. Keeping the plain file on SD makes it readable for others... I also tried to encrypt the file to the internal directorxy (context.getFilesDir()). I noticed copying files to this folder makes them corrupt.... Also this folder is not secure, since the root user can read

3) May third approach will be as in 2., to decrypt the file to SD and read it with another viewer, with the hope:

- that I can advice the app to open the PDF only with this one app
- that this viewer does not allow to share the app while reading
- that the file can quickly be deleted while the viewer shows it, without crashing the viewer

Do you have any ideas about a PDF-viewer that meets this requirements or do you have other ideas to protect a PDF while reading?

Comment: In the end you are trying to create a DRM system with too many components that are not in your control. It is not likely that you will be able to make such a system secure.